# Open a modal and update url without reloading the main page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I have primereact datatable (it is separate component **InvoiceTable** and it is part from another bigger copmonent **AccountDetails**) with many columns- every column has a selection mode and a button. When I click the button, it opens a new modal and changes the url.
The url of the main page (**AccountDetails**) is *customers/customerCode* and when I open the modal (I click on the icon from the **InvoiceTable**) it becomes *customers/customerCode/invoiceNumber/changelog*.

The issue is that when I select any invoices and open the modal, the main page is refreshed and the selected invoices are unselected.

These are the methods which I use:

```
  openHistoryModal = (rowData, e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.history.push(`/customers/${customerCode}/number/changelog`);
  };

  discardHistoryModal = (e) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/customers/${customerCode}`);
  };
```

I tried with history.replace and window.history.replaceState but the result is the same. I use only class components.

I have the following Routes as well:

```
              <ProtectedRoute
                path="/customers/:customerCode/"
                component={(props: any) => <AccountDetails {...props} />}
                authority={[userRoles.user]}
                feature={"Collection module"}
                rootStore={this.props.rootStore}
                exact={true}
              />
              <ProtectedRoute
                path="/customers/:customerCode/:number/changelog"
                component={(props: any) => <AccountDetails {...props} />}
                authority={
                  [userRoles.userAudit.toString()] || [userRoles.admin]
                }
                feature={"Collection module"}
                rootStore={this.props.rootStore}
                exact={true}
              />
```

These are the methods in the ProtectedRoute component:

```
checkAuthority = (roles) =>{
   return this.props.rootStore.userStore.hasRoles(roles)
  }
 
  checkFeature = () => {
    let featureActive: boolean = false;
    const foundFeature =
      this.props.rootStore.managementStore.featureFlags.filter(
        (flag: { name: string; value: string; type: string }) =>
          flag.name === this.props.feature && flag.value === "true"
      );
 
    if (
      (foundFeature && foundFeature.length > 0) ||
      this.props.feature === "alwaysActive"
    ) {
      featureActive = true;
    }
 
  return featureActive
 
  };
 
  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <Route
        {...props}
        render={(props) =>
          this.checkAuthority(this.props.authority) && this.checkFeature() ? (
            <Component {...props} rootStore={this.props.rootStore} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to='/404'></Redirect>
          )
        }
        exact={this.props.exact}
      />
    );
```

I will be very grateful if you could give me some ideas and help me out!

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] for all the relevant code you are working with, specifically I'd like to see the `ProtectedRoute` component's implementation. From what I see, it seems you are using a `Route` component's `component` prop with an inline function which remounts an instance of the component it's rendering.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for the answer. This is the component ProtectedRoute: https://pastebin.com/GtAtWiYe

Comment: Can you edit your post to include that relevant code? I'm on a VPN and can't view the pastebin right now.

Comment: Yes, sure. It is updated.

Comment: Since the private route is rendering the `component` prop on the `Route` component's `render` prop, try passing `component={AccountDetails}` instead. If there's still further issues, think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?